# How to properly use Dispose in Unit Of Work Pattern?

Tags: entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work

I know this question has been asked several times before, but I couldn't get the answer I was looking for.
So, I've implemented the Repository (generic) and UOW pattern, so I can access my DB using EF. Here's part of the UnitOfWork class:

```
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                entities.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

The question is: Who is calling the void Dispose method?? I've seen no example of the usage of that method.

this it the upper part of the Unit Of Work class:

```
    private BDEntities entities = null;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        if (entities == null)
        {
            entities = new BDEntities();
        }
    }
```

Is this right? should I use "Using"? and if yes, than why do I need the Dispose method?

Can you give me an example of a proper and simple usage?

Thank you,
Rotem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you have not come across any examples about who calls the dispose is because UoW is usually used together with dependency injection and a dependency injection container, like Autofac. And in this case, it is the responsibility of this container to create objects and dispose of them later. Granted, this is not the only way UoW can be used, but it is a common pattern.

As for answering your question: I think the approach that you are taking is more or less right. The UoW class should be the one that wraps the context, so it should be the one to dispose it as well (essentially, the DbContext itself is a UoW).

You can simplify the Dispose method though. Since you do not have any unmanaged and not `IDisposable` resources (like pointers), it is completely enough to call the Dispose method of the context in the Dispose method of the UoW:

```
 public void Dispose()
 {
   entities.Dispose();
 }
```

(No other `Dispose` method, no `SuppressFinalize` calls).

And yes, you should absolutely use `using`. And that's exactly why you need a the `Dispose()` method; only objects that are of a type that implements IDisposable can be used in a `using` block. If you write a using block, it basically translates to a try-finally block; your code from inside the using block goes into the try block, and in the finally, the `Dispose()` is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So basically, the method should look like:
            
            if (entities == null)
            {
                using (entities = new BSODEntities()) { };
            }

and I don't really need the Dispose method, since the "using" already encapsulates it? right?

Comment: Yes, that's basically how I think it should be used. As for the Dispose() method: you don't have to call it explicitly when you're done with the object, if you use a using block. But you do need to implement it in your class as shown, so it can be called by that encapsulated call from the using block.